# SAP Hybris - Avoid displaying Assisted Service Mode (ASM) on pages

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

**Hybris 6.5**

My project got an existing B2B storefront (say, sf1) and I created one more B2B storefront (say, sf2) from sf1, by 
adding

```
 'meta key="modulegen-name" ...' to sf1's extensioninfo.xml.
```

I made necessary changes for the new storefront and could access successfully on the browser. The only problem is, 
Assisted Service Module (ASM) appears all the time on the top. I would like to show ASM only with query string URL access like ' ?asm=true' .

Is there any way to disable ASM and show it only on '?asm=true' URL access.

The existing storefront doesn't have ASM appearing and it shows only on '?asm=true' URL.

I'm new to Hybris and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the ASM Module comes through an CMS Component to the site. So if you have 2 different content catalogs you could it handle on this way. Otherwise you have to implement some logic, that this component will only be shown if you set some URL property like '?asm=true'

BR

Comment: Thanks. I removed ASM from cms cockpit, synched to online and now ASM is not appearing. At the same time, it's not appearing for the '?asm=true' access, I will thoroughly check the code of existing storefront (sf1) and believe some code might have been present which shows ASM only for '?asm=true'.